# Richfaces placeholder not working

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, richfaces

I'm using jsf 2.0 and I'm trying to use Richfaces 4.3's placeholder. Here's the jsf code

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core"
      xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich">
....
....
<h:form>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    <h:outputText value="Header"/>
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <h:inputText id="first" value="#{bean.firstValue}">
                        <rich:placeholder value="Fill me"/>
                    </h:inputText>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</h:form>
```

This is how it's being rendered:

```
<form id="j_id_1v" name="j_id_1v" method="post" action"/mypage/app/main.xhtml" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                "Header"
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <span id="j_id_1v:j_id_2r">
                    <script id="j_id_1v:j_id_2rScript" type="text/javascript">
                        <!--
                        new RichFaces.ui.Placeholder("j_id_1v:j_id_2r", {"targetId":"j_id_1v:first","text":"Fill me"} );
                        //-->
                    </script>
                </span>
                <input id="j_id_1v:first" name="j_id_1v:first" type="text" value>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</form>
```

The #{bean.firstValue}" is null, not an empty string. Not sure if this matters or not. The problem is that the placeholder text is not showing up.

Any ideas?

--EDIT--
Checking the js console, it says "Richfaces not defined". I'm sure I'm using richfaces 4.3.

Comment: The place I work for has its own maven repository. I have access to richfaces, but there is no primefaces. So I can't add new stuff, only use what they have in their repo.

Comment: Okay, nevermind the previous comment then.

Comment: No prob. I've noticed that the rendered richfaces is wrapped by <!-- //-->. Not a single example I've seen has that. I'm not sure if that's what's messing my stuff up, but it's pretty weird. :/

Comment: This doesn't harm. It's just to prevent prehistoric webbrowsers which doesn't support `<script>` elements from choking, such as Netscape 1.0. It's indeed questionable why you see this back in HTML code these days. Those browsers are not in use anymore for almost a decade. RichFaces is just somewhat overzealous as to attempting to achieve maximum browser compatibility.

Comment: Interesting... Still, can't understand what's going on with the placeholder. By any chance, can a css style interfere with a placeholder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so, I figured it out after a ton of research. Turns out that jsf 2.0 and richfaces don't get along if you use `<head>`. You have to use `<h:head>` so it inserts all the required dependencies. And... that was it!

Answer (score 1):

For me worked adding an ajax support to inputText e.g.

```
<h:inputText id="first" value="#{bean.firstValue}">
    <rich:placeholder value="Fill me"/>
    <a4j:ajax/>
</h:inputText>
```